# JVM and CLR allocation optimization

Tags: memory-management, jvm, stack, allocation

Do the JVM and .NET VM allocate objects on the stack when it is obvious to the runtime that an objects lifetime is limited to a certain scope?

Comment: Could you elaborate on when it is *obvious*? I'm not sure about it...

Comment: Well Coming from the C, C++ world, it seems pretty obvious...
Since in Java and .NET, the VM knows every reference to an object. If you create an object within a method and never transfer that anywhere else, it would make sense to keep it on the stack. A stack anyway exists for passing arguments, so why not benefit from superfast ( and super simple ) stack allocation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JVM does this.  It can actually remove the allocation totally, under the right circumstances.

Quoting this [article.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275.html)

> The Java language does not offer any way to explicitly allocate an object on the stack, but this fact doesn't prevent JVMs from still using stack allocation where appropriate. JVMs can use a technique called escape analysis, by which they can tell that certain objects remain confined to a single thread for their entire lifetime, and that lifetime is bounded by the lifetime of a given stack frame. Such objects can be safely allocated on the stack instead of the heap. Even better, for small objects, the JVM can optimize away the allocation entirely and simply hoist the object's fields into registers.

More information on [Escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) from Wikipedia.

Comment: What version of the JVM does this?  More importantly, does the latest one support Escape Analysis?

Comment: Java 6 update 14, you had to enable it with a command line option.  (-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis).  It looks like it was removed in update 18, then added back again in update 21.  I'm not sure if the command line option is still required or not - but I'd use it just be safe.